# Siri thinks the city on my Facebook is one of my home addresses

Tags: ios, siri, facebook

When I want to use Siri involving my home address, such as navigate home or remind me something when I get home, it always asks me to clarify "which home address?" It gives one option that is the home address I put in my contact card in Contacts (it lists the street name and number), and it has another home address (it doesn't list anything, but I believe it's referring to an address that it imported from being connected to Facebook, and that address just has the city (not the street).

I don't want Siri to think that the Facebook entry is something to ask me about every time. What can I do to fix this? I'd rather not erase the city I have in Facebook. And I'd rather not erase the home address I have on the phone and put my full home address in Facebook. Seems like a basic thing.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, more or less. On iOS 10 on my contacts card, I was able to edit the identification my phone gives the Facebook address by scrolling down to the connected accounts section of my contact card and editing the Facebook content there. However there is a bug and even after I'm done editing the only options are "edit" and "cancel" but not something to save it.

So instead I went to macOS, opened my contacts card there, edit my information there more easily, and it sync'ed to my iPhone, so Siri works properly now.